# Which mathematical algorithm is used for interpolation between datapoints in Smooth Line Chart of Echart?

Tags: angular, graph, echarts

Which mathematical algorithm is used for interpolation between datapoints  in Smooth Line Chart of Echart ?

Is it polynomial fit or Bezier smoothing? I just want to know which mathematical model is used for interpolation for the echart feature given below

https://apache.github.io/echarts-handbook/en/how-to/chart-types/line/smooth-line

I have tried googling, but could not find out which one exactly. Any references that reveals the underlying mathematical model of Echart would be helpful

Comment: The source code is availabe on [github](https://github.com/apache/echarts/tree/master).

Comment: I imagine they are [cubic splines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)#Algorithm_for_computing_natural_cubic_splines) but not be sure